# Question about Atwood Machine and Changing Masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Say we have an object of X Newtons on the ground called object 1, and it is connected to another object called object 2.  If we change the mass of object 2 in intervals until object 1 < object 2, how would the force the the ground exerts on object 1 change and how would it be if object 2 was greater than object 1.  I know that the force would be less as object 2's mass increase, but I'm not sure how to display it in my problem with numbers.

Would we have to do something with the tension as the mass increases?  We can find the acceleration with the two masses but I don't understand conceptually how we could find how the force the ground exerts changes.

Comment: Hint: think about Newton's Third Law.

Comment: @garyp I know that for sure lol!  I know that the second law states $f = ma$ and I can find the acceleration value for the whole system and also the tension values, but I'm not sure how to translate those into force or mass.

Comment: If I understand the question (object 1 on the ground, object 2 suspended in air via Atwood's machine) then I don't think you have to calculate the acceleration of anything.  The question asks for forces.  Tension plays a role.  Count up all the forces on object 1. How many are there?  What are their values?

Comment: @garyp I figured the problem out, I was thinking about the problem in a different manner, I thought something totally different, but in the end you were correct.  I found the tension values and subtracted from the original weight values and found the forces.  Thank you for the help!